# Loopback: how to collect data in a for-loop containing a async method?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

Using loopback I have a simple for loop in which I perform a findOne:

```
let my_data = [];
Orders.forEach(function(order,idx) {

  let postalcode = order.toJSON().customer.postal_code;
  let ps4 = postalcode.slice(0,4);

  app.models.postalcode.findOne({where: {postal_code: parseInt(ps4)},include: ['depot']}, function (err, Postalcode) {
    if (err) {
      winston.error('Could not load postalcode %s due to error %s: ', ps4, err.message);
    } else {

      if (Postalcode) {
        let depot = Postalcode.toJSON().depot;
        if (!depot) {
          //
        } else {
          let depot_city = depot.city;
          if (cities_to_process.indexOf(depot_city) > -1) {
            my_data.push(order);
          } else {

          }
        }
      } else {
        winston.warn('Could not find postal code %s', ps4)
      }
    }
  });
});

console.log(my_data);
```

After the for loop I would like to do something with the collected data in my_data. Since findOne appears to be asynchronous, what is the preferred way of doing this?

Comment: use `async` library. It will be easy for you to use `async.eachSearies()` to loop the async function in series

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal that seems to work for me. if u can put this in an answer I will mark it as solved.

Comment: I have added a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async` library. It will be easy for you to use `async.eachSearies()` to loop the `async` functions in series and get the desired output. You can take a reference here [link](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#synchronous-iteration-functions)

Answer (score 1):

You can create new promises in forEach like:

```
let Y = X.forEach((item) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('done')
  })
})

Promise.all(y, callback)
```